# Filtering a text file with a series of pipes

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a homework assignment where we're supposed to filter input through a series of pipes.  I've gotten the program working where `cat` pipes a file to the first filter without issue, but when I try to add the 3rd fork, I run into issues where the program just hangs and requires an interrupt to exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pfd[2];
    if(pipe(pfd) == -1) {
        perror("could not create pipes");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch( fork() ) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork 1");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            /* child:
             *  r = false
             *  w = true
             */
            if( close(pfd[0]) == -1 ) {
                perror("close 1");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if( pfd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO ) {
                if( dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("dup2 1");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if( close(pfd[1]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("close 2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            execlp("cat", "cat", argv[1], (char *) NULL);
            perror("cat failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            /* parent */
            break;
    }

    switch( fork() ) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork 2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            /* child:
             *  r = true
             *  w = true
             */
            if( pfd[0] != STDIN_FILENO ) {
                if( dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("dup2 2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if( close(pfd[0]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("close 4");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            if( pfd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO ) {
                if( dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("dup2 3");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if( close(pfd[1]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("close 5");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            execlp("sed", "sed", "s/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g", (char *) NULL);
            perror("sed failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            /* parent */
            break;
    }

    switch( fork() ) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork 3");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            /* child:
             *  r = true
             *  w = false
             */
            if( close(pfd[1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("close 5");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if( pfd[0] != STDIN_FILENO ) {
                if( dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("dup2 4");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if( close(pfd[0]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("close 6");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            execlp("tr", "tr", "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", (char *) NULL);
            perror("tr failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            /* parent */
            break;
    }

    if( close(pfd[0]) == -1 ) {
        perror("close 7");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( close(pfd[1]) == -1 ) {
        perror("close 8");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( wait(NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("wait 1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( wait(NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("wait 2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( wait(NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("wait 3");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I've based this code off an example from *The Linux Programming Interface* by Michael Kerrisk (sec 44.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you need "filter input through a series of pipes". But I see that you create only one pipe (one pipe() call creates one pipe and returns two file descriptors - two pipe ends). If you have 3 childs - you need at least 2 pipes connect in the right order.

```
stdin -> child1 -> PIPE1 -> child2 -> PIPE2 -> child3 -> stdout
```

This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059723/how-do-i-use-two-pipes-in-unix-c) should help.

Comment: Ah, rereading the textbook, I see where I went wrong. I was thinking the pipe was duplicated during the forking process. Thank you.